# Why in this phrase, does the verb not require an "s" on the end if it refers to a noun?

Tags: nouns

Why we should use "involve", and not "involves" in this example:

> "So, what does this specialization involve?"

It seems to me that the verb should be in the form "involves" since it is refers to the noun "specialization":

"Verbs with a third-person singular noun or pronoun (he, she, boat, courage) as a subject ever have an added s on the end"

Comment: This seems like it would be better suited to English Language Learners SE.

Comment: It's because of the presence of "does". The auxiliary verb "do" requires the verb that follows it to be an infinitival verb-form, and that is what "involve" is, an infinitive, not a tensed verb-form like "involves".

Comment: +1 for observing the apparent contradiction and lucidly explaining what you did not understand.  It's a complicated bit of English syntax.

Comment: @BillJ, I understand then that the rule you mentioned have preeminence over the other one.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It might help if you look at the 'un-fronted' version: "[So,] this specialization does involve what?"  {'does involve' = 'involves'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "involve" here instead of "involves" because there is an auxiliary verb as the main verb here (do/does). Auxiliary verbs typically take an infinitive or the bare infinitive (without the "to"), so we use "involve" with "does"